# Error in Copying table in SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014, insert-into

I need to remove fields from existing table `FullNAICS` and copy fields from another table `NAICS_NEW`. `FullNAICS` having dependencies and unable to drop the table.I need `FullNAICS` table name and all fields from `NAICS_NEW`.
I am trying to copy table but getting the error, Please advise.

Query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.FullNAICS  
   SELECT *
   FROM dbo.NAICS_NEW
```

Error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>
> String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

I have my table design as follows:

`NAICS_NEW` Table design:

```
NAICS_US_CODEvarchar(6) 
[INDUSTRY TITLE]varchar(100)    
NAICS2d varchar(2)  
NAICS3d varchar(3)  
NAICS4d varchar(4)  
NAICS5d varchar(5)  
NAICS6d varchar(6)  
[Naics2d.txt]varchar(72)    
[Naics3d.txt]varchar(87)    
[Naics4d.txt]varchar(95)    
[Naics5d.txt]varchar(97)    
[Naics6d.txt]varchar(100)
```

`FullNAICS` Table design:

```
NAICSCd6d   nvarchar(255)   Unchecked
NAICA6dTxt  nvarchar(255)   Checked
NAICSCd5d   nvarchar(255)   Checked
NAICS5dTxt  nvarchar(255)   Checked
NAICSCd4d   nvarchar(255)   Checked
NAICS4dTxt  nvarchar(255)   Checked
NAICSCd3d   nvarchar(255)   Checked
NAICS3dTxt  nvarchar(255)   Checked
NAICSCd2d   nvarchar(255)   Checked
NAICS2dTxt  nvarchar(255)   Checked
[NAICS US CODE] nchar(10)   Checked
[INDUSTRY TITLE]    nchar(10)   Checked
        Unchecked
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tables are using varchar and nvarchar,nchar

if you want to suppress the message use CAST and CONVERT
for all columns

SELECT
 CAST(NAICS_US_CODE as nvarchar) , 
CAST([INDUSTRY TITLE] as nvarchar), CAST ....
FROM dbo.NAICS_NEW

CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928.aspx